# how to filter data with checkbox click?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

> i have filter from SQL and i use AND condition for that , i want to
>   filter like if i check two check box then data comes combination of
>   two ,if check three then data comes combination of three but in my
>   case if i selected one check box then data comes as i like but if i
>   select multiple then no record comes...how to get records:-

```
IF(@USER_TYPE_S !=0)    SELECT @SQL =   @SQL+' AND USER_ID=@XP_STUDENT'  
IF(@USER_TYPE_BUIL !=0) SELECT @SQL =   @SQL+' AND USER_ID=@XP_DEALER'
IF(@USER_TYPE_B !=0)    SELECT @SQL =   @SQL+' AND USER_ID=@XP_CUTOMER'
IF(@USER_TYPE_OWN !=0)  SELECT @SQL =   @SQL+' AND USER_ID=@XP_OWNER'

SELECT @PARAMETER_LIST='@XP_STUDENT INT,@XP_DEALER INT,@XP_CUTOMER INT,@XP_OWNER INT'
INSERT INTO #TEMP(PROJECT_ID)

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL,@PARAMETER_LIST,@USER_TYPE_S,@USER_TYPE_BUIL,@USER_TYPE_B,@USER_TYPE_OWN
```

Comment: Where are you retrieving values from the check box? Can you show us that code?

Answer (score 0):

In your case the SQL Query before executed on the Server would be something like

```
Select * from table where USER_ID="Test1" AND USER_ID="Test2"...
```

So, are you sure there will be such records with USER_ID matching different filters. Perhaps you are required to use `OR` condition instead of `AND` condition

Comment: if i use or condition then whole data comes.